# If you slice an oval into four segments with perpendicular lines do the diagonal segments have the same area?

Tags: trigonometry

[image: Diagram of the problem]

Hello Math folk... Please help settle a debate that my wife and I have since I'm not quite sure how to approach this mathematically... and yes, this is about pizza.

A circle or oval is sliced into four slices, those slices are made perpendicular to each other. The slices may or may not intersect the centre of the shape.

I believe that the sum of the area of two diagonal slices (shown as A) is equal to the area of the remaining two slices (shown as B). Please could you help prove or disprove this?

Bonus: Does it matter how the oval is sliced? Do the slices have to be across the longest and shortest points?

Comment: Have you tried drawing a few and checking? It's a general *"not at all!"* but there are situations that allow for it.

Comment: You can see that it's generally not true for a circle when the lines meet at its boundary.

Comment: FYI: You may be interested in the related [Pizza Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pizza_theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no:

[image]

Here, the intersection of the two orthogonal cuts is very close to the edge. It should be obvious that the left blue region alone contains more than half of the pizza. (Give that part to your wife.)

Comment: Wow, this makes it painfully obvious... I concede ‍♂️